# What's the reason for Illegal Invocation in this extended DocumentFragment?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I tried to extend `DocumentFragment` object.

```
function DocFragment() {
    this.addHTML = function(html) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = html;
        while(div.firstChild) this.appendChild(div.firstChild);
    };
}
DocFragment.prototype = document.createDocumentFragment();

var doc = new DocFragment();
doc.addHTML("<b>after</b><i>list</i>");
```

However I got `Illegal Invocation` error on `this.appendChild` line. I know it is a bad idea to extend host objects, I'm just curious why this error appeared? Is there any other appropriate way to add some methods to DocumentFragment beside passing it to some function like `function addHTML(doc, html)`?

Answer (score 2):

This is more or less the difference between `document.createDocumentFragment()` and `new DocumentFragment()`. `document.createDocumentFragment()` does some opaque initialization that you can’t copy.

> Is there any other appropriate way to add some methods to `DocumentFragment` beside passing it to some function like `function addHTML(doc, html)`?

To take that literally, you can extend its prototype just fine:

```
DocumentFragment.prototype.addHTML = function (html) {
    // …
};
```

You can also take the “jQuery approach” (a wrapper):

```
function DocFragment() {
    this.fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
}

DocFragment.prototype.addHTML = function (html) {
    // Use this.fragment
};

// Copy properties and methods as necessary
```

Defining `addHTML(doc, html)` is much cleaner than both of these, though.

Comment: According to [this link](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) it is a bad idea to code `DocumentFragment.prototype.addHTML` because exposure of DOM prototypes objects are not guaranteed (although most browsers including IE9+ implements these interfaces as regular objects). In the "jQuery approach" it is hard to expose all the DocumentFragment members. Sure, I can iterate them, at least those which are enumerable, but again, this is not guaranteed by DOM Level 2. Thanks for useful answer, but I'm still sad...

Answer (score 1):

You could try directly extending the prototype for DocumentFragment.

```
DocumentFragment.prototype.addHTML = function(html) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = html;
    while(div.firstChild) this.appendChild(div.firstChild);
};
```

Or if you are squeamish about this, you could try just extending (in jQuery or Underscore or something) like so:

```
var DocFragment = _(DocumentFragment).extend();
```

Comment: Thanks for a good suggestion, but iterating DocumentFragment.prototype is not defined and can even lead to unspecified errors due to DefaultValues. See [this link](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-4.3.8), especially the parts about host objects - DOM objects are part of this weird family.

Comment: Ah, you are right! I threw that in for completeness sake but I realize now (and reading your comment above) that this requires a bit more thinking.